# How to store global addresses in database?

Tags: database, database-design, street-address, postal-code

Currently we have the following US-centric database design for storing addresses:

```
street_address_1 text
street_address_2 text
city text
state_province text
postal_code text
country text
```

But now I've learned that some countries do not use any state_province classification. Now that we are improving the database, is there any other way to make this database more international-friendly?

Comment: Is there anything in your question not covered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159756/how-should-international-geographical-addresses-be-stored-in-a-relational-databa already?

Comment: Thank you, that's it. Feel free to flag this duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should international geographical addresses be stored in a relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159756/how-should-international-geographical-addresses-be-stored-in-a-relational-databa)

Answer (score 1):

Nope, sadly you probably won't get this to 100% ever. Depends what you use it for? I'd consider why you are splitting out the separate segments in the first place and just KISS and have an [Address] column if it suits your use case. Have a read of this for all the problems about structuring addresses:

https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/

And an interesting project trying to eliminate the problem although sadly not usable for most things yet;

https://what3words.com/