# Relationships between Master and Transaction tables

Tags: mysql, database-design, entity-relationship

I defined Master tables (data definition tables, static in nature) to generate content in my web page; and Transaction tables to store data entered by users (these tables are dynamic in nature). Consider following example:

Set of Master tables consisting of `State` having 1:M relationship with `City`, `City` having 1:M relationship with `Locality`. A Transaction table `User` to store personal details entered by a user. The `User` table has address attributes like Address, State, City and Locality. These can be defined as 1:M relationships from corresponding Master Tables (a particular record in `State`, `City`, `Locality` tables can be a part of multiple records in `User` table).

[image]

Is the design correct? I think it's sufficient to define 1:M relationship between `Locality` and `User` tables since the other two attributes (City and State) can be obtained from relationships between the Master tables. Would it be better to change the ER design to the following?

[image]

Are there alternatives to my requirement?

Comment: Your first design violates [3NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form).  The second design is normal.

Comment: So, can I go with my second design? Or are there any better alternatives?

Comment: You may like to read the following related questions: [Best practices for storing postal addresses in a database (RDBMS)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/310540) [Is there common street addresses database design for all addresses of the world?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/929684) [How should international geographical addresses be stored in a relational database?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1159756) [What is the “best” way to store international addresses in a database?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24481)

Comment: @eggyal, the relationships described in the question are just an example of one of the possible cases. What I need to know is whether it's appropriate to define relationships between the Master and Transaction tables like I've done in the above example.

Thanks for the links though. :)

Comment: A good general rule of thumb is to "*normalise until it hurts; then denormalise until it works*".  On that basis, option #2 is the best option unless/until you encounter problems that require an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

What queries do you have?  Do you ever need to search by `state` or `city`?  Even if you do search by those, it may not impact what I am about to say...

Since `locality`, `city`, and `state` are 'nested' and it is not likely for the names to change, I suggest that both of your options are "over-normalized".  One table with all three items in it is the way I would go.

As I see it, there are two main reasons for normalizing:

- Locating some string that is likely to change.  By putting it in a separate table and pointing to that table, you can change it on only one place.  This is not needed in your example.
- Saving space (hence providing speed, etc).  This does apply in your example, but only at the `locality` level, not at `address`.  You might argue that `city` and `state` can be dedupped; I would counter with "The added complexity (extra tables) does not warrant the minimal benefit.".

A side note:  If `locality` is `zipcode`, then your option 1 is in trouble at least one place I know of:  Los Altos and Los Altos Hills (two different cities in California) *both* have sections of zipcodes 94022 *and* 94024.

Comment: how can I store all of them in one common table?

Comment: 4 columns: id (PRIMARY KEY), locality, city, state.